# Using Vue dynamic route name, in component function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I've been trying to make a dynamic view rendering, with Vue and Laravel. However, i can't wrap my head around how i am supposed to parse the dynamic parameter, to the component function.

```
Router.map({
    '/cms-admin/:page': {
        component: {
            template: returnView(this.$route.params.page)
        }
    }
});

function returnView (option) {
    // Generate the AJAX request here
}
```

Through documentations i've read, that $route should solve the issue. I can parse $route into the view, and print the text on the page. However, i can't use $route inside the map, to get the dynamic name?

Say, i enter "/cms-admin/dashboard", 'dashboard' should get parsed down to the template parameters.

Thanks in advance,
Steven

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. register the individual templates for the pages as [partials v1](http://v1.vuejs.org/api/#Vue-partial) [v2](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Vue-partial-removed)
2. use `<partial>` and `$route`

js:

```
component: {
  template: '<partial :name="partial" v-if="partial !== ''"></partial>',
  data() { return { partial: '' } },
  ready() { this.partial = this.$route.params.page},
}
```

Note: Not sure whether you can access `this.$route` in `data()`, therefore I used the `ready()` event, but maybe you can drop that and put it directly in `data()`.